# rundeck SCM Import GitLab Pull data

Tags: rundeck

Successfully setup the SCM Import plugin but it does not pull the data from Gitlab automatically.
Do I need to create job to pull the data?
Shell script commands?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By design, you can't obtain the jobs automatically, after configuring the SCM import you must go to the Jobs page > Job Actions (Right button) > Import Remote Changes, then select the remote jobs to pull and Import.

To configure SCM import:

1. Select your project and go to the left panel and select "Projects Settings", then click on the "SETUP SCM" element.
2. Go to the "Import" section and click on the "Setup" button.
3. Scroll down and check the "Git Repository" section, the Git URL must be filled in the following format to connect via HTTPS method: `http://user@git_hostname:port/git/user/repo.git`, e.g: `http://root@yourgitsolution/git/root/rdeck_jobs.git`.
4. Scroll down and select `.*\yaml`  in the "Regular Expression" section. In the "Format" textbox (Source Files section) select "yaml". At the end put the Git account user password created previously in the key storage.
5. Click on the "Setup" button, and now the configuration is saved.
6. Now go to the jobs section (left panel) If the repository contains jobs you will see a blue icon message, put the cursor in that message and you will see the number of jobs available to import to the Rundeck instance.
7. To import it click on the "Job Actions" button and then on "Import Remote Changes".
8. Then Rundeck shows the available jobs to import, click on the "Import" button.
9. Now, the jobs were imported to the Rundeck instance from the Git repository.

The "Pull automatically" option in the SCM config automatically pulls remote changes on automatic fetch.

Comment: thanks MegaDrive68k! I have community version, the pull feature is only available on the enterprise version, right?

Comment: I don't see the Import Changes option.  I see message -- Import Status : Not Tracked. Is because I'm using community version? thanks!

Comment: Which rundeck version are you using? those steps are available on 4.6.1 (latest at this moment).

Comment: Rundeck 4.6.1 2022-09-14 -- Community version

Comment: You can try using the "clean" button (at the SCM config) or just re-configure from scratch. The question doesn't cover these details please update your question with more details about your Rundeck config and remote Git Repository.